# Type of createAsyncThunk request with Redux Toolkit

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

**Context** : I want to set in Redux store the response from my API when the user logs in.
For that, i use `createAsyncThunk` as the [documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) says.

**Problem**: With my code, I get the following error :

```
Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<any, { email: string; password: string; }, AsyncThunkConfig>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'
```

How can I solve this ?

Here is my code :

**My code** :
loginSlice.ts

```
export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk("LOGIN", async (data: { email: string; password: string }) => {
    const response = await Logs.login(data.email, data.password);
    console.log("response", response);
    return response.data;
});

const loginSlice = createSlice({
    [...]
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder.addCase(loginUser.pending, (state, action) => {
            state.loading = true;
        });
        builder.addCase(loginUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.loading = false;
            state.data = action.payload;
        });
        builder.addCase(loginUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.loading = false;
            console.log("state", state);
            console.log("action", action);
        });
    },
});

export const loginReducer = loginSlice.reducer;
```

Login.tsx

```
[...]
const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<ILoginData> = (data) => {
      dispatch(loginUser(data));
};
[...]
```

PS : `data` is just an object with `email` and `password` from the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the default Redux `Dispatch` type does not know about thunks, because they are an optional middleware that extends the store's behavior.

That's why we specifically direct users to infer an `AppDispatch` type based on the actual store setup, and use "pre-typed" React hooks that have the store types baked in.  That way your components have the correct types for usage situations like this:

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start#define-typed-hooks

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store'

// Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector`
export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector
```